# Llamar a dll en c# desde código c++

Tags: c#, c++

Hace poco me han pedido crear una dll con C# para consumirla desde c++. Llevo mucho tiempo programando en c# pero nunca hice nada parecido. Buscando por ahí me encontré una una librería llamada `UnmanagedExports` y tiene muy buena pinta pero la documentación es bastante escasa. A esto hay que sumarle que jamas programé nada en c++ por lo que ahí estoy bastante perdido.

El caso es el siguiente. Tengo mi dll en c# con el siguiente código:

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpLibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [DllExport(ExportName = "maxElement", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static int maxElement(int a, int b)
        {
            if (a > b) return a;
            else return b;
        }

        [DllExport(ExportName = "concatString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        [return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public static string concatString(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string a, 
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string b
        )
        {
            return a + b;
        }

        [DllExport(ExportName = "changeArray", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public static string[] changeArray(
            [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)] ref string[] a,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string b
        )
        {
            string[] c = new string[a.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                c[i] = a[i] + b;
            }
            return c;
        }

        [DllExport(ExportName = "updateArray", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static void updateArray(
            [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)] ref string[] a, 
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string b
        )
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                a[i] = a[i] + b;
            }
        }

        public class Test
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        [DllExport(ExportName = "createObject", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static Test[] createObject(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)] ref string[] a
        )
        {
            Test[] c = new Test[a.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                c[i] = new Test() { Value = a[i] };
            }
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

No estoy muy seguro de si está bien usada la libreria `UnmanagedExports` en cada uno de los tipos de entrada y salida.

Despues, como de c++ no tengo ni idea, he buscado por ahí como consumir esta dll y he encontrado un ejemplo que me ayudo a consumir el primero de los métodos:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>

using std::string;

using MaxElementFn = int(__stdcall *) (int a, int b);
using ConcatStringFn = string(__stdcall *) (string a, string b);

int main()
{
    HMODULE mod = LoadLibraryA("CSharpLibrary.dll");

    MaxElementFn maxElement = reinterpret_cast<MaxElementFn>(GetProcAddress(mod, "maxElement"));
    std::printf("max: %d\n", maxElement(1, 2));

    ConcatStringFn concatString = reinterpret_cast<ConcatStringFn>(GetProcAddress(mod, "concatString"));
    std::printf("concat: %s\n", concatString("a", "b"));

    bool end = true;
}
```

La llamada al método `maxElement` se está haciendo correctamente y me devuelve y pinta el valor correctamente, pero la llamada al método `concatString` me esta lanzando una excepción:

```
Excepción producida en 0x7B3E170C (ucrtbased.dll) en Test.Net.exe: 0xC0000005: Infracción de acceso al leer la ubicación 0xCCCCCCCC.
```

¿Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal? ¿y algun ejemplo de como consumir el resto de funciones de la dll desde c++?

Llevo ya varios días con estoy y no consigo avanzar, espero me podais ayudar.

Un saludo.

**Actualización 1**

He consguido hacer que las llamadas a los metodos `concatString` y `maxElement` funcionen correctamente. Ahora voy a por el metodo `changeArray` que tiene como entrada un array de string y un string, y devuelve un array de string. He añadido en el código c++ el siguiente using:

```
using ChangeArrayFn = char ** (__stdcall *) (const char **a, const char *b);
```

y en el código he incluido la siguiente llamada:

```
ChangeArrayFn changeArray = reinterpret_cast<ChangeArrayFn>(GetProcAddress(mod, "changeArray"));
const char  *colour[4] = { "Blue ", "Red ", "Orange ", "Yellow " };
char **col = changeArray(colour, "change");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    std::printf("- change: %s\n", col[i]);
```

No me da error de código pero cuando realiza la llamada a `changeArray` lanza una excepción:

```
Excepción no controlada en 0x751A4402 (KernelBase.dll) en Test.Net.exe: 0xE0434352 (parámetros: 0x80131535, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x720D0000).
```

¿Como puedo hacer la llamada con los array desde c++? ¿En que me estoy equivocando?

Comment: No tengo repuesta, estoy enfrascado en un problema similar, pero en sentido contrario, mi problema es usar dll desarrolladas en C++ en lenguaje C#, algo similar, solo con la diferencia que en cada lenguaje lleva exportar e importar; pero tu pregunta es amplia, se nota que investigas y no te detienes, tal ves no recibas ninguna respuesta; pues muchas veces cuando las cosas se ponen peliagudas no hay respuestas, pero se que continuaras y encontraras tu solución, esa es mi forma de actuar, pregunto, si recibo respuesta lo agradezco enormemente, si no continuo, siempre encuentro una solución.